# Are there any other Star Wars references in Firefly?

Tags: star-wars, firefly, easter-egg

According to [this article on mental floss](http://mentalfloss.com/article/56022/23-fun-facts-about-firefly), there are Star Wars easter eggs in the series Firefly.

> Star Wars was a big influence on Whedon. Captain Malcolm Reynolds somewhat resembles Han Solo, while Whedon used the Millennium Falcon as inspiration to create Serenity. In fact, you can spot a few spacecraft from George Lucas's magnum opus on the show.
>
> When Inara’s shuttle docks with Serenity in the pilot episode, an Imperial Shuttle can be found flying in the background. In the episode “Shindig,” you can see a Starlight Intruder as the crew lands on the planet Persephone.

And this photo shows Han Solo in carbonite (In miniature):

[image]

Are there any other Star Wars references or craft appearances in the Firefly television show?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be all the intentional references.

For the sake of completion here are all four known references.

- **Serenity was inspired by the Millenium Falcon**
  This is not strictly an in-show reference, but as you mentioned in your question, Whedon did use the *Millennium Falcon* as inspiration for  *Serenity*.
- **An Imperial shuttle appears in the pilot episode**
  In *S01E01 The Train Job* you can see a [Lambda-class T-4a shuttle](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lambda-class_T-4a_shuttle) (the ship Darth Vader steps off in the second Death Star) fly overhead.
- **The *Starlight Intruder* in Episode 6**
  As you also mentioned in your question, in *S01E06 Shindig* you can see the (now) Legends ship *[Starlight Intruder](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Starlight_Intruder)*.
- **Han Solo in carbonite**
  While you mention it only in that picture, it shows up several times throughout the show. Rumor has it that they snuck Carbonite-Solo into every episode. You can see a list [here](http://www.geekwithcurves.com/2011/01/han-solos-in-firefly.html) of all the known locations. Note it is probably lacking given that it is 7 years old at this point.